# PyQt5 - Make labels in a grid expand dynamically without covering other items

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a `QGridLayout` instance in a window, to which I dynamically add a series of widgets, depending on which values are checked on another `QListView` instance.

For each checked item in the list, I add a slider and two labels (for value and name), on a row of the layout, in positions 0, 1, 2.

```
    for index in range(self.model.rowCount()):
        if self.model.item(index).checkState():
            slid = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
            sl_val_lbl = QLabel("--")
            sl_val_lbl.setMaximumWidth(150) #(a)
            #sl_val_lbl.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding,QSizePolicy.Expanding) #(b)
            sl_name_lbl = QLabel(self.model.item(index).text())
            #sl_name_lbl.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding,QSizePolicy.Expanding)
            self.sliders.addWidget(slid,index,0)
            slid.setMaximumWidth(200)
            self.sliders.addWidget(sl_val_lbl,index,1)
            self.sliders.addWidget(sl_name_lbl,index,2)
            self.sliders_dict[sl_name_lbl.text()] = (slid,sl_val_lbl,sl_name_lbl)
```

Now, the issue I have is that some of the `values` the label takes, are actually pretty long strings.
My first solution was (a), i.e. set a certain size for the label. Of course, this may or may not work depending on the actual size of the text to be rendered, and when said text is only few chars long as in the case with floats, this is not a very clean solution.

I then went on trying (b), i.e. setting the expanding policy of the `Qlabel` to `Expanding`. This works fine for the label itself, however it goes to overlap with the next `Qlabel` in the Layout (column 2), covering its value.

In other words, I was expecting the underlying layout structure to stretch with the contained Widgets, which is not happening.

How to obtain the desired effect of having the size of the column in the layout to follow/adapt to that of the contained widgets?

Comment: I think you should make your own Label object to make a clear distinction between the stored string and the rendered string (so, for example, long strings appear like "This is a long st...") depending on the size of the Label widget (perhaps by re-implementing resizeEvent). Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure. They way I understand this, it looks to me that the Label stretches to accommodate the length of the stored string, and does this correctly. However, the size of the underlying grid does not change accordingly, so that the new label ends up covering its right-side neighbouring label.
I need to force a kind of "redraw" for the layout, I think.
A brute-force approach would be to - maybe - delete and recreate the labels each time the value has changed, but that sounds like inelegant overkill.

Comment: Well the layout will be redraw if you resize the window. Does this solve the layout issue? If so try calling a resize with the current window geometry whenever you need this solution (this should not change the actual size but in theory should emit the resize signal). I'm assuming your layout has been set in the parent (i.e. `self.setLayout(gridbox)` for example).